# How to specify a path dependency to fallback to a wheel in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I am currently implementing multiple serverless functions in Python which share a `base` package in the same repository.

Due to the restriction in folder structure of a Cloud Function, `../../libs/base` is not available in production environment.

What I planned to do is to build a wheel for `base` and place it in the same directory as the serverless function who uses it.

Regardless of all these context, I actually want to ask if it is possible to configure a `pyproject.toml` to look for `../libs/base` first, and fallback to `dist/base.whl` when the former does not exist?

I tried something like below:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
base = [
  { path = "../../libs/base", develop = true },
  { path = "dist/base.whl", develop = false }
]
```

But `poetry` complained:

```
Because clover-s3-events-watcher depends on both base (0.0.26) @ file:///workspace/libs/base and base @ file:///workspace/projects/function-1/dist/base-0.0.26-py3-none-any.whl, version solving failed.
```

Sorry for my broken English and appreciate any help :)